# Need to print a page in three parts

Tags: positioning

I need to use TeX to fill in a form that is three parts of a page, the width is always 8.5in, the length of each part is 3 1/3 in each.

The problem I am having is getting the 2nd and 3rd parts to print exactly 3 1/3" and 6 2/3" down the page.   How do I go about setting this up?

Comment: We need more information. If you are using LaTeX, you can use minipages with fixed heights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`flowfram` README](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram):

> The `flowfram` pack­age en­ables you to cre­ate frames in a doc­u­ment such that the contents of the `doc­u­ment` en­vi­ron­ment flow from one frame to the next in the or­der in which they were de­fined. This is use­ful for cre­at­ing posters or mag­a­zines, in­deed any form of doc­u­ment that does not con­form to the stan­dard one or two col­umn lay­out.

Here's an example that seems to replicate what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=5mm}% Just for this example
\usepackage[draft]{flowfram}

\newflowframe[1]{\textwidth}{3.3333in}{0pt}{\dimexpr\textheight-3.3333in}

\newflowframe[2]{\textwidth}{3.3333in}{0pt}{\dimexpr\textheight-6.6667in}

\newflowframe[3]{\textwidth}{3.3333in}{0pt}{\dimexpr\textheight-10in}

\pagestyle{empty}% Remove all headers/footers

\begin{document}

First block

\newpage

Second block

\newpage

Third block

\end{document}
```

The `draft` option to `flowfram` just prints the frames as they are defined, and would not be needed in your document.

You can adjust the dimensions of the blocks to suit your needs using the following definition for `\newflowframe`:

```
\newflowframe[<pages>]{<width>}{<height>}{<x>}{<y>}
```

Comment: WOW, this is exactly what I was looking for!   Thanks, it is a lot easier then what I was trying to do.